# Need guidance on sub-templating method in C++

Tags: c++, templates, generics, lambda

I got this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    template<class S>
    function<S(T)> transform;
};

int main()
{
    obiekt.transform = [=] (int element) { return (float)element; };
}
```

How can I make the transform function generic with a second type? I am not asking on how to add a second type to `A` like `A<int, float>`. I know how to do that.

Comment: If this were legal, it would mean that an `A<int>` object contains a `function<void(int)>` member object, a different `function<int(int)>` member object, a different `function<std::vector<char>(int)>` member object, etc. etc.

Answer (score 4):

You will need some form of type erasure for that. You see, choosing what lambda a particular `std::function` will contain is a runtime decision. You cannot decide at runtime what would the return type will be.

To allow any return type, you will probably need `std::any`:

```
#include <any>

template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    function<any(T)> transform;
};
```

[Live working example](https://godbolt.org/z/bzdbsMfoc)

If you know all possible type `transform` may return, a variant would be more appropriated:

```
#include <variant>

template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    using return_type = variant<int, float, string>;
    function<return_type(T)> transform;
};
```

[Live working example](https://godbolt.org/z/M5c17GjYr)

Both of those snippets will enable your main to compile.

---

Of course, you can also decide everything at compile time, even the lambda type. That would allow a single one template parameter for the `A` type, while allowing any return type:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
    A(T t) : transform{t} {}
    T transform;
};

int main() {
    // The compiler will deduce something like A<lamda#1-type>
    A obiekt{
        [=] (int element) { return (float)element; }
    };

    float a = obiekt.transform(1);
}
```

[Live working example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ko6rcMfTr)

What I'm proposing in this third example is to drop the type erasure and simply use the template parameter for the whole lambda type. A lambda has its own type, different for each lambdas. `std::function` is a type erasure wrapper around any callable type, just like `std::any` but with a `operator()` defined.